# Is there a way to declare function parameter types in R?

Tags: r, function, parameters, introspection

If one has a function declaration in a package. Parameters are declared without type which could be figured out only in run-time, when the function is called.

Is there a means to describe R function parameter types so that those descriptions would be available of static analysis?

Use-case: introspection for an IDE.

==== EDIT ====

- Annotations?
- Meta-descriptors?
- etc.

Comment: The Bioconductor [TypeInfo](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/TypeInfo.html) package, from Duncan Temple Lang,  provides a way to specify (and introspect) type. It is more-or-less orthogonal to using S4, and requires annotation by hand. It has been used to automatically create Java wrapers around R code, although this is not for the faint of heart.

Comment: check the `lambda.r` package: https://www.r-bloggers.com/functional-programming-with-lambda-r/

Answer (score 2):

Generally not, `R` is dynamically typed which can be a great advantage or burden.  Any object in `R` has a type of course, and these can often be coerced (or cast) but I don't think that's what you are asking about.  You might want to look into the class system (`?class`) for some approaches.  But generally, it's up to the function-writer to check the input values before using them.  Also, you might find this [paper](http://r.cs.purdue.edu/pub/ecoop12.pdf) interesting.

Check out `?browseEnv` and perhaps the code that drives it might be of interest to your project. Or [RStudio](http://rstudio.org)?

Comment: nice, especially the formal calculus part :)

Comment: I can't comprehend that part at all, but I have found the rest of it to have some very useful insights, especially if you have worked in several lanaguages.

Answer (score 0):

The R package `assertthat` (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/assertthat/index.html) provides some help in this space. It works well with `testthat` for doing testing in packages where typing is a concern.